# Work in FastReport send SQL code and error Required Param value not set

Tags: sql, fastreport

Error Required Param value not set
Code:
SELECT id_vst,
CASE
WHEN id_sys = 155 THEN CAST('Visible' AS varchar(80))
ELSE CAST(' ' AS varchar(80))
END AS result
FROM DOC_ACC_CNT